# API Platform - Get collection where Author is User

Tags: api, platform

I currently have an *Offer* entity which has an *author* property, like so :

```
#[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: User::class, inversedBy: 'offers')]
#[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
private $author;
```

Currently, when I do a get request on */offers/*, I get a collection of ALL the offers, which is normal.
I would want to only retrieve the *offers* where the author is the logged in user instead. (basically a `findBy(['author'=>$this->getUser()])`)

After searching on the internet I've been trying the following, which obviously is not working

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: OfferRepository::class)]
#[ApiResource(
    normalizationContext: [
        'groups' => ['read'],
    ],
    itemOperations: [
        'get' => [
            'security' => 'object.author == user',
        ]
    ],
    collectionOperations: [
        'get' => [
            'security' => 'object.author == user',
        ]
    ]
)]
class Offer
{
...
```

This gives me the following error :

> hydra:description: "Warning: Undefined property:
> ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Paginator::$author"

Which tells me this is completely the wrong approach.

Kind of stuck here, any hint ?
Thank you.

Comment: Paginator is used to populate collection, so your object is a collection. You could parse the collection to manually reject the results you don't want. It would be better to not get them at all tho. Also if you could add on which framework your working it could help attract the right poeple to your question

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit late but this is answered by implementing an "extension". That would allow the collection to be filtered to match only items with a specific condition (in your case, a User).

There's an old issue (here: https://github.com/api-platform/core/issues/1481).

And official documentation here: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/extensions/#example.